# What is the best way to append filesystem::path elements to another path?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, std

I'm trying to append selected elements from one path to another. But the path.append method doesn't work as I would expect it to. Looking at it's implementation it will accept elements from a string, but not from a path, which seems bizarre. Given a pair of path iterators that select a range of path elements I see no way to append that to an existing path or use it to initialise a new path.

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std;

void TestPathAppend()
{
   path path1("c:\\dir1\\dir2");

   // Fails - constructor cannot construct a path from selected path elements.
   path path2(path1.begin(), path1.end());

   // Ok - constructor _can_ construct a path from a random chunk of string.
   string random("stuff");
   path path3(random.begin(), random.end());

   // Fails - path.append cannot append path elements.
   path path4;
   path4.append(path1.begin(), path1.end());

   // Ok. path.append can append elements from a random chunk of string.
   string random("someoldcobblers");
   path4.append(random.begin(), random.end());

   // What I want to do but can't.
   path::iterator temp = path1.begin();
   advance(temp, 2);
   path4.append(temp, path1.end());
}
```

More generally the path class interface just seems badly designed. It exposes begin() and end() methods making it possible to iterate over the elements of the path and giving the impression that it is intended to abstract a path as an iterable set of path elements, but no push, pop, append or constructor methods that would actually enable you to use the path elements you can iterate. It has a constructor and append() method that accept an iterator range pair, but that can't even accept other path iterators and only works for string iterators, which is totally redundant since you can already construct a path from a string and append one path to another, so those string iterator methods don't even  enable any additional functionality, they just duplicate functionaity that is already available.

Am I misunderstanding how this type is intended to be used?

What is the best way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: I ran in to the exact same issue. Seems like a incomplete interface. These operations should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you want to do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <numeric>
int main()
{
    path ab("/a/b");
    path cdefgh("c/d/e/f/g/h");

    auto first = std::next(cdefgh.begin(), 2);
    auto last = std::next(cdefgh.begin(), 5);

    auto adefh = std::accumulate(first, last, ab,
                                 [](auto p, const auto& part)
                                 {
                                     return p /= part;
                                 });

    std::cout << adefh << std::endl;
}
```

expected results:

```
"/a/b/e/f/g"
```

Comment: That's just appending a string to a path. What I'm trying to do is append an iterator range from one path onto another path.

Comment: A range of characters or a range of path elements?

Comment: Sorry no, it's appending one path to another. But still not quite what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes. A range of path elements.

Comment: Yes. That's it.

Comment: Of cource you can use the operator/ but 
path path2(path1.begin(), path1.end());
should just work!

Answer (score 0):

I found the same question asked for the Boost implemention and the solution works for VS2012.

```cpp
void TestPathAppend()
{
   path path1("c:\\dir1\\dir2");
   path::iterator temp = path1.begin();
   advance(temp, 2);
   path path2;

   while(temp != path1.end())
   {
      path2 /= *temp;
      ++temp;
   }
}
```

It does seem unnecessarily clunky though and not really in keeping with the design philosophy of the rest of the standard library. E.g. if path exposed the standard iterable collection interface I'd be able to use the copy method or a back_inserter iterator to do this instead of needing a hand-rolled loop.